# Modify ChangeStream Responce In Loopback 3

Tags: loopbackjs, server-sent-events, changestream

First off, if you're not familiar with change streams, please read [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Realtime-server-sent-events.html).

It seems, when using `lb` to scaffold applications, that a change stream endpoint is automatically created for models. I have already successfully implemented a change stream where, on submitting a new model instance to my `Statement` model the changes are sent to all connected clients in real time. This works great.

Except it only sends the `modelInstance` of the `Statement` model. I need to know a bit about the user that submitted the statement as well. Since `Statement` has a `hasOne` relationship with my user model I would normally make my query with an `includes` filter. But I'm not making a query here... that's not how change streams work. The node server sends the information to the client without any query for that information being sent first.

My question is, how can I hook the outgoing changestream in the Statement model so that I can pull in the needed data from the user module? Something like:

```
module.exports = function(Statement) {

  Statement.hookChangeStream(function(ctx, statementInstance, cb) {
    const myUser = Statement.app.models.myUser
    myUser.findOne({ 'where': { 'id': statementInstance.userId } }, function(err, userInstance) {
      if (err !== undefined && err !== null) cb(err, null);

      // strip sensitive data from user model
      cleanUserInstance = someCleanerFunc(userInstance);

      // add cleaned myUser modelInstance to Statement modelInstance
      statementInstance.user = cleanUserInstance;
      cb(null, true);
    }
  });

}
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: I've found something here, maybe you can create your own changeStream like [here](https://github.com/strongloop/angular-live-set/issues/11#issuecomment-186938308)?